# Sending `C-c C-c` to the process window without swithcing to it

Tags: window, ess, comint

In ESS mode, I sometimes send some code to the process buffer and want to cancel it using `C-c C-c`. Can I do this without actually switching to the process window from the script window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to write your own function for doing this.

You'll want to read up on the functions `get-buffer-process` and `signal-process` to learn about how to send the right signal to the ESS process.

Here is an example: An interactive function that sends a SIGINT to a buffer of your choosing.

You can modify this function to target whatever ESS buffer you want or keep it as is.

```
(defun interrupt-buffer-process (buffer)
  "Send a SIGINT to BUFFERs process."
  (interactive (list 
                (completing-read 
                 "Buffer: "
                 (mapcar 'buffer-name (remove-if-not 'get-buffer-process (buffer-list))))))
  (signal-process (get-buffer-process buffer) 'sigint))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That did it!

Answer (score 3):

You can do `M-x ess-interrupt`.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry not sure how to paste this as a comment, this works for ESS:

```lisp
(defun my-interrupt-ess-buffer-process ()
  "Send a SIGINT to script's iESS process."
  (interactive)
  (signal-process (ess-get-process-buffer) 'sigint))
```